# Reproducing GRASS GIS network analysis tutorial in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, field-calculator, network, road

I'm looking to reproduce the assigning of road speeds as denoted in a GRASS GIS tutorial (v.net.alloc tutorial), where the road speed is assigned by road type (i.e. 'interstate' = 75 mph etc.) to then work out the 'cost' of travelling on that road (i.e. drive time analysis).

I have the road type in one column, I have calculated the road length in another, I now wish to set the speed limit of the road by road type, however I can't work out how to do this in QGIS using the field calculator.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CASE` statements (essentially an `IF THEN ELSE` statement) to determine the speed limit by road type.

First either select to *Create a new field* (and determine whether you want integer, string etc. I will assume string) or *Update an existing field* and use an expression similar to the following:

```
CASE 
WHEN "road_type" = 'lane' THEN '35 mph'
WHEN "road_type" = 'interstate' THEN '75 mph'
WHEN "road_type" =  'dirt_track' THEN '120 mph'
ELSE '0 mph'
END
```

[image: Field Calculator]

Although not required, it might be useful to use double-quotes (" ") for field/column names, single-quotes for values (string or integer). An `ELSE` statement is not required but if any features do not fall into any conditions you set, they will be recorded as `NULL`.

Comment: Cheers, this worked a treat!

Comment: Nice one buddy! Glad you got it working :)